# Sysbench Memory Test

Tags: linux, memory, cloud, benchmarking, sysbench

I have done memory test on my cloud instance with Sysbech utility.

**Using following command:**

sysbench --test=memory --memory-block-size=1K --memory-scope=global --memory-total-size=100G --memory-oper=write run

**During the Run:**

TOP command result

**I never found Mem % is increased.
but CPU usage increased upto 100%**

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 5664 root      20   0 78036 2704 1908 S 99.5  0.4   0:09.42 sysbench
    1 root      20   0 19276  500  348 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.81 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
```

is it strange ?

What does Memory test in Sysbench actually mean ?